# How can we get posted data to my url from a third party website in laravel5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a website. It is created using laravel 5.6. I integrated a payment gateway (payone) that is working fine. I can do test transactions. But I don't know how can I capture the post data posted by payment gateway to my url (https://demo.project.de/payment/response). I had tried some functionality but not working. Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

**routes->web.php**

Route for getting post from payment gateway (payone)

```
Route::post('/payment/response', 'PaymentController@response')->name('payment.response');
```

**PaymentController.php**

```
public function response()
    {
        // you'll need to include the $defaults array somehow, or at least get the key from a secret configuration file
        if ($_POST["key"] == hash("md5", env('KEY'))) {
            // key is valid, this notification is for us
            echo "TSOK";
            if ($_POST["txaction"] == "appointed") {
                dd($_POST);
                // a freshly created transaction has been marked successfully initiated
                // update that transaction accordingly, e.g. by $_POST["reference"]
            }
            if ($_POST["txaction"] == "paid") {
                dd($_POST);
                // update your transaction accordingly, e.g. by $_POST["reference"]
            }
        }
    }
```

**Payone response**

`response of your webserver:`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <HTML LANG="EN"> <HEAD> <META CHARSET="UTF-8"> <META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" CONTENT="IE=EDGE"> <META NAME="VIEWPORT" CONTENT="WIDTH=DEVICE-WIDTH, INITIAL-SCALE=1"> <TITLE>PAGE EXPIRED</TITLE> <!-- FONTS --> <LINK HREF="HTTPS://FONTS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM/CSS?FAMILY =RALEWAY:100,600" REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="TEXT/CSS"> <!-- STYLES --> <STYLE> HTML, BODY { BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFF; COLOR: #636B6F; FONT-FAMILY: 'RALEWAY', SANS-SERIF; FONT-WEIGHT: 100; HEIGHT: 100VH; MARGIN: 0; } .FULL-HEIGHT { HEIGHT: 100VH; } .FLEX-CENTER { ALIGN-ITEMS: CENTER; DISPLAY: FLEX; JUSTIFY-CONTENT: CENTER; } .POSITION-REF { POSITION: RELATIVE; } .CONTENT {
```

Comment: Try on the function to get the request input , something like

Comment: show your response output

Comment: The code looks ok. Is it your URL publicly available in order the 3rd party sevice be able to find it?

Comment: Generally those services have some test post requests. Can you try one and check what happens?

Comment: @sam, I have added request input. But not working

Comment: @KuldeepMishra. I have included the response message from payone in my question

Comment: Try to make a post request by yourself to your url with postman to find out what happens

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas, I have checked in payone mechant webiste. My transaction response is `PAGE EXPIRED`. I have included response in my question.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas, I will try with postman. I have written route in `web.php`. Do postman works with web.php?

Comment: Yes it works, the Postman or any other such tool does not care where you have specified your route, but it only needs your route to be accessible. You need to further understand how HTTP works.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas. Thanks I will test it.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas I tested in postman. I am getting posted elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on that function

```
public function response(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    // then here you should have the parameters received from the payone and process as required in the $data variable

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reason for not getting the response from payment gateway.

1: In payment gateway the response url was wrong. They are posting in to I wrongly entered url.

2: My route doesn't have public access it is inside auth middleware.

Now response is getting and working fine.